# QNetworkAccessManager parsing JSON

Tags: json, qt

I am new to Qt. Started looking into to get around the restraints of HTML5 mobile applications. I am trying to parse JSON Data in Qt. The idea is that the app will use SQLite for offline mode and connect to an API When online. I found a guide online but it does not seem to work right with my API

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QUrlQuery>
#include <QWebSettings>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QJsonArray>

void sendRequest();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    sendRequest();
    return a.exec();
}

void sendRequest() {

    // create custom temporary event loop on stack
    QEventLoop eventLoop;

    // "quit()" the event-loop, when the network request "finished()"
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

    // the HTTP request
    QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1") ) );
    QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
    eventLoop.exec(); // blocks stack until "finished()" has been called

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

        QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();

        //parse json
        qDebug() << "Response:" << strReply;
        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());

        QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();

        qDebug() << "username:" << jsonObj["username"].toString();
        qDebug() << "password:" << jsonObj["password"].toString();

        delete reply;
    }
    else {
        //failure
        qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
        delete reply;
    }
}
```

API

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "username": "admin", 
        "password": "qwerty"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "username": "chris", 
        "password": "1234"
    }
]
```

The result im getting is:

```
Response: ""
username: ""
password: ""
```

Comment: QJsonDocument::fromJson takes an optional 2nd argument, which provides an error, if there is one. I suggest using this and checking to see if any error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the value of `strReply` which is an empty QString I don't think that JSON parsing has anything to do with your problem. Documentation for `readAll ()` states that:

> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty QByteArray() can mean either that no data was currently available for reading, or that an error occurred.

which looks like what's happening here. Your code should work but I would check the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1` again. I don't know what kind of API is it but it looks strange that it would return the JSON you pasted without providing some additional parameters in the URL.

*edit*:

Your API returns a JSON array but you are handeling it like an object. Instead of `QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();` try:

```
    QJsonArray json_array = jsonResponse.array();

    foreach (const QJsonValue &value, json_array) {
        QJsonObject json_obj = value.toObject();
        qDebug() << json_obj["username"].toString();
        qDebug() << json_obj["password"].toString();
    }
```

Comment: Okay I am using `django-rest-framework`. If I change the URL to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/?format=json I get:`Response: "[{"id":1,"username":"admin","password":"qwerty"},{"id":2,"username":"chris","password":"1234"}]"
username: ""
password: ""`